# Entity Framework misreading stored procedure on function import newbie

Tags: entity-framework

im no expert in ef so this will be almost certainly my fault but here goes...

any idea why this sp is being imported into ef, and ef says it has no output?

```
SELECT TaxiAuthority.AuthorityID, [Cardiff_region_1].NAME
FROM [Cardiff_region] AS [Cardiff_region_1] INNER JOIN YourCompany_TaxiAuthority ON Cardiff_region_1].ID = TaxiAuthority.LALinkID WHERE geom.STIntersects(@point) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL doesn't parse. You have:

```
SELECT  TaxiAuthority.AuthorityID, [Cardiff_region_1].NAME
FROM    [Cardiff_region] AS [Cardiff_region_1] 
        INNER JOIN YourCompany_TaxiAuthority ON Cardiff_region_1].ID = TaxiAuthority.LALinkID 
WHERE geom.STIntersects(@point) = 1;
```

`TaxiAuthority` doesn't exist. Try with:

```
SELECT  TaxiAuthority.AuthorityID, [Cardiff_region_1].NAME
FROM    [Cardiff_region] AS [Cardiff_region_1] 
        INNER JOIN YourCompany_TaxiAuthority AS [TaxiAuthority] ON [Cardiff_region_1].ID = TaxiAuthority.LALinkID 
WHERE geom.STIntersects(@point) = 1;
```